# Give AskUbuntu its own "magic link": [AU] instead of [ubuntu.SE]

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

You know those "magic links" you can use in comments or chat? You type `[se]` and get [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) or `[so]` for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). In comments, there is also e.g. `[edit]` which links to the current question/answer's edit page.

Now where the mother site *[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com)* and really big sites like *[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)*  and *[Super User](https://superuser.com)* and even the smaller site *[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)* all got a short magic link (`[se]`, `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`), [**Ask Ubuntu**](https://askubuntu.com) still uses the long magic link with the `.se` suffix: **`ubuntu.se`**, although even its URL does not contain `.stackexchange.com` any more! Same with [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) (`unix.se`), but they also still are a subdomain of StackExchange.

**Now as [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) is the 3rd largest site in the Stack Exchange network after [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) and [SU](https://superuser.com) and before [SF](https://serverfault.com) and has its own domain which is no subdomain of `stackexchange.com`, I propose and request the magic link to be shortened to *`[au]`* instead of <del>`[ubuntu.se]`</del>!**

Give [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), our now over 5 years old favourite website in the world, the respect it deserves!

Comment: Seconded, and thanks for sharing this, I didn't know about it!

Comment: I agree! We are not Ubuntu.se anymore!

Answer (score 7):

I like this idea and it seems to me to a be reasonable request and quite likely a far from onerous task. [au] seems a reasonable choice to replace [ubuntu.se] and I think we could all appreciate saving a few keystrokes (certainly my sloth-like typing speed would benefit.)

Comment: I really don't think we need separate answers for this. Upvotes on the question show support, if someone has something useful to say against it they can post their own answer.

Comment: @Seth Ok, just trying to cover all the bases - Deleted.  Any input on [this?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16790/isnt-a-comment-in-reply-to-a-deleted-comment-obsolete-by-default)